# Can I create and switch between multiple taskbars / screens on a single monitor?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

On Windows 7, with a single monitor, I want to distribute my open programs between two separate taskbars (or screens), and switch between these taskbars as necessary. For example, when working on two separate projects, I'd keep the programs that deal with each project on its own taskbar or screen.

I can vaguely recall doing something like this on a linux distro years ago, so I am curious if W7 has this functionality, either built in, or through a downloadable program? How about W10?

Thanks, and sorry if this has been answered before, when I search for it, everything I get is about doing this on multiple monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a virtual desktop manager such as https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/desktops